# block restrict depending on role

Tags: blocks

I use this snippet to restrict block visibility from administrator

```
<?php
global $user;
if (user_access('access administration pages') || ($user->uid == 6)) {
  return FALSE;
} else {
  return TRUE;
}
?>
```

I also want to restrict this block from role 6. However, it does not work. Can somebody help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Check to see if $user has the administrator role.
  if (in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) {
    // Do something.
  }
```

Replace "administrator" with the role name you want to check.

EDIT:

If you want to check for role id's use below code.

```
global $user;
$role_ids = array_keys($user->roles);
if (in_array(6, $role_ids)) {
  // Do something
}
```

In your case

```
<?php
global $user;
$role_ids = array_keys($user->roles);
if (user_access('access administration pages') || (in_array(6, $role_ids))) {
  return FALSE;
} else {
  return TRUE;
}
?>
```

Comment: hello, I probably did not explained it enough. I need this block to be restricted from administrator (whichis role 1) and role 6 as well.

Comment: Check updated solution !!

Answer (score 0):

`$user->uid` is the user ID, which is different from the role ID of the role assigned to the user.

If you want to avoid that users having the role with ID equal to 1 (or 6) see the block, you should use the following code.

```
<?php
  $roles = $GLOBALS['user']->roles;
  return (!isset($roles[1]) && !isset($roles[6]));
?>
```

If with administrator you mean the first user created when Drupal is installed, then you should use the following code, supposing that you are still interesting in avoiding the users with the role #6 see the block.

```
<?php
  global $user;
  return ($user->uid != 1 && !isset($user->roles[6]));
?>
```